# DBCP Tomcat Connection pooling removeAbandoned not working

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, profiling, connection-pooling

I have configured **Tomcat DBCP** as:

```
<Resource
name="jdbc/myoracle"
auth="Container"
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:mysid"
username="abc"
password="abc"
maxActive="20"
maxIdle="4"
minIdle="0"
maxWait="4"
removeAbandoned="true"
logAbandoned="true"
removeAbandonedTimeout="3"
/>
```

I don't know, I have defined the above settings as correct or not. 
I am using struts 2, A web page has menu link and that is calling action class where I am performing all db operations and opening/closing the connections from/to pooling.
Problem is, if i am continuously keep on clicking the menu link say 40-50 times, the connections are increasing where as single mouse click, and then wait for response, is doing fine(i.e. not increasing connections).

Only **continuous mad clicking** without waiting for single response makes **connections** to rise **abruptly** and not coming back to initial. 
If my connections are leaking somewhere in action class, then why it's been doing fine always for single mouse click, wait for response and then another mouse click?

(Continous Clicking on same menu link results:)
As I have defined maxActive as 20, Connections are going till 24 (as i can remember) and after that pool is exhausted i.e. new connection/request waits indefinitely to get a connection from exhausted pool.

Here my doubt is, Why **removeAbandoned has not been  closing connections** as i have specified removeAbandonedTimeout=3. 
If i **assume i have a connection memory leak** or I am not closing any connections deliberately, then **removeAbandoned will kill all those opened connections or not**?

or is there any wrong with my DBCP settings or above parameters? 
Please help me to sort this out.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the value of the `maxWait` parameter is too small. According to [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Common_Attributes), its unit of measure is milliseconds. When all the available connections are allocated, in your case it will wait for only 4 milliseconds and will throw an exception.

Also, I'd recommend increasing the value of the `minIdle` parameter value, so that at all times there will be several "prepared" connections available to be used. Of course, you might need to additionally increase the value of the `maxIdle` parameter value afterwards.

As for the `removeAbandonedTimeout` parameter, make sure that its value is **more than** the number of seconds that is required to run any database operation.

One more thing to keep in mind is that setting `logAbandoned` to true adds some overhead to the connection borrowing process.

Comment: I tried increasing the values a bit, but still it's going same. 
I understand removeAbandonedTimeout value needs to be more than the no. of seconds that is required to run any db operation to avoid connection breaking.
But Doesn't removeAbandonedTimeout="3" mean to close connections/ or take away back even running mode connections to pool?

Comment: Why after 50-60 continuous mouse clicks, connection pool gets exhausted and stops allocating any more connections?

Comment: What you mean saying "increasing values a bit"? The thing is that all of your values are much less then defaults are (removeAbandonedTimeout = 60, maxActive = 100, maxIdle = maxActive = 100, minIdle = initialSize = 10, maxWait = 30000). Do you have any specific reason to use values much smaller than the default ones? Bottom line, if you need more connections, why not allocate more?

Comment: How much connections I am going to allocate, all will get exhausted because somewhere it's connections leak in my code.. and why removeAbandoned="true" is not closing connections in this case?

Comment: Maybe that's simply because there's no reason to mark connections as abandoned and remove them? Go read the documentation, it looks like you're not really following the meaning of the removeAbandoned parameter. Also, take a loot what `timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis` means.